# NvChad: How to add a theme into the builtin list of `nvchad themes`?

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, nvchad

I have installed a new theme called "rigel" in NvChad. I can switch to this theme from commandline using the command `:colorscheme rigel`.

Is it possible to add this theme to the builtin list of the `nvchad themes` command?

Additionally, when I set `:colorscheme rigel` the statusline colors become undistinguishable from the buffer colors. How to solve this issue?

[image: Colors undistinguishable]

Comment: "my suggestion would probably be to make a PR to the above repo with the theme you want" https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad/issues/347#issuecomment-903477619